# Declare a variable with quotes around it

Tags: excel, vba

At the moment I want to declare a variable and give it the value "C1" (Including the quotes)

In the same way that that I can get C:5 by doing

```
DeclaredVariable = "C" & ":" & "5"
```

I have tried something like

```
AfterRange = """ & "C1" & """
```

but this give me the error "Expected: end of statement" and highlights the part with C1 on it

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Try this `AfterRange = """C1"""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these give the output "C1". But you should consider looking into `ranges`

```
AfterRange = Chr(34) & "C1" & Chr(34)

AfterRange = """C1"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Each " must be doubled by another one. Inside the string use "" and at the string margins use """ (an extra one quote). If you need ONLY double quotes, you must use """". There are two margins...

Beside that, `Chr(34)` means also a quote.